# New to JSReport with Angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, jsreport

i am using Angular 10 and would like to intergrade JSReport into my program to print report (pdf).
For JSReport, i already setup the server and create a sample report and test it using 'postman', everything OK.
and the Angular already download ( npm install jsreport-browser-client-dist )
and come out below code :

```
    grdInvoiceMToolbarPrint() {
    this.ProSvr.GetRpInvoice(this.AuthSvr.branchID, "INV5000000050").subscribe((rMsg: ResponseMessage) => {
      this.rpInvoice = [];
      this.rpInvoice = (rMsg.data as RpInvoice[]);

      const request = {
        'template': { "name": "invoice" },
        'data': JSON.stringify(this.rpInvoice)
      };

      
      //this.jsreport.serverUrl = this.ProSvr.urlReport;
      //this.jsreport.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + btoa('admin:password');
  
      // this.jsreport.renderAsync(request).then(function(res) {
      //   const html = '<html>' +
      //           '<style>html,body {padding:0;margin:0;} iframe {width:100%;height:100%;border:0}</style>' +
      //           '<body>' +
      //           '<iframe type="application/pdf" src="' +  res.toDataURI() + '"></iframe>' +
      //           '</body></html>';
      //   const a = window.open('about:blank', 'Report');
      //   a.document.write(html);
      //   a.document.close();
      // });
      
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.rpInvoice));
    });
  }
```

i have read the document https://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client , but do not mention anything. Up to this point, i cannot proceed due to the 'this.jsreport' is not defined, please help!

Comment: Make sure you imported JSReport and used dependency injection in the constructor for it

Comment: Do you have a constructor and in import that you can post by the way?

Comment: i don't have constructor and import. I only have 'jsreport-browser-client-dist' and i also don't know how to import. is ' import ????? from jsreport-browser-client-dist' ?

Comment: I assumed this was a frontend package.  I guess you are using JSReport in node.js, not Angular

Comment: Not understand.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code in this file?

Comment: Hi, i manage to import it. like : import * as jsReport from 'jsreport-browser-client-dist'; 'this.jsreport' change to 'jsreport' this will done.

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as jsReport from 'jsreport-browser-client-dist';
...
...
 grdInvoiceMToolbarPrint() {
this.Svr.GetRpInvoice(this.AuthSvr.branchID, "INV5000000050").subscribe((rMsg: ResponseMessage) => {
  this.rpInvoice = [];
  this.rpInvoice = (rMsg.data as RpInvoice[]);

  const request = {
    'template': { "name": "invoice" },
    'data': JSON.stringify(this.rpInvoice)
  };
  jsReport.serverUrl = this.Svr.urlReport;
  jsReport.renderAsync(request).then(function(res) {
    window.open(res.toDataURI())
  });
});
```

}

*** the import * as jsReport XXXXXXX can change to import * as abcXyz XXXXXXXX

Comment: can you tell which npm package to install jsreports for angular ?